# How can I pass a props from component A to C while has a B between both?

Tags: react-native, tabnavigator, react-props

I need pass some props to my child component, but I have a tabNavigator between the file that contains the props and the file that will receive the props.

Example:

Home.js: (this is the component that holds the props)

```
export default class Home extends Component<{}>
{
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <TabNavigator
                    changeScreen={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile'))//this is the props
                />
            </View >
        );
    }
}
```

TabNavigator.js:

```
const MainScreenNavigator = TabNavigator({
    tab1: {
        screen: ChatScreen
    },
    tab2: {
        screen: NoMatterScreen
    }
})
```

ChatScreen.js: (this is the component that I need to use the props sended form Home.js

```
export default class ChatScreen extends Component<{}>
{
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <Button
                    onPress={() => this.props.changeScreen())
                />
            </View >
        );
    }
}
```

The problem here is the TabNavigator, how can ChatScreen receive a props from Home if there's a TabNavigator between both? Just to make clear, the props that Home are sending is from a DrawerNavigator, inside my DrawerNavigator I have Home and Profile screen.

Comment: You have 2 options: 1. [redux](https://redux.js.org) 2. [provider](https://medium.com/@bloodyowl/the-provider-and-higher-order-component-patterns-with-react-d16ab2d1636)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use Redux but here a link you can use to solve your issue with some changes in your code.

```
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/nesting
```

Or you can still give it a try by adding TabNavigator to home.js

```
export default class Home extends Component<{}>
{
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <MainScreenNavigator
                    changeScreen={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile'))//this is the props
                />
            </View >
        );
    }
}
const MainScreenNavigator = TabNavigator({
    tab1: {
        screen: ChatScreen
    },
    tab2: {
        screen: NoMatterScreen
    }
})
```

When you pass props to a TabNavigator, it is distributed to all its children.

Comment: "Or you can still give it a try by adding TabNavigator to home.js"
Was exactly what I did and didn't worked...

Comment: I'll try lean how to use redux.